# Is white wine permitted between 6 and 7 o'clock?

Tags: sources-mekorot, shabbat, minhag, grapes-wine, kiddush

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23107/9643) references the possibility that there is a distinction between red and white wine for [those that are careful](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23100/9643) not to make *kiddush* between 6 and 7 o'clock. Are there any sources that mention such a distinction?

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer [recorded here](http://www.chabad.org.il/Questions/Item.asp?ArticleID=3117&CategoryID=68) from Rav Yosef Simcha Ginzburg (Rav of Omer and the weekly Halacha contributor to Sichat Hashavua), there is no distinction between white or red wine, or any wine at all - the limitation is on making kiddush at that time. In fact if one were to be making kiddush on challa the limitation would still apply

Comment: The OP knew that there was debate on the matter as mentioned in his linked answer. The question was "Are there any sources that mention such a distinction?"

Comment: @doubleaa ,So if someone writes "no" as an answer that would be ok? If there are no sources ,there are no sources. This answer explains why there wouldn't be any sources because it has nothing to do with the wine.

Comment: @sam correct, saying no would be an answer. It may not be convincing without any support. The fact the R Yosef Ginzberg says it doesn't have to do with wine doesn't mean there aren't other opinions out there